# What practical difference does Linker /SUBSYSTEM make in a server application?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2017, com

I only recently discovered this linker setting and I am wondering in an application which has no UI and is run on a server, does it make any difference which I use?

I quite enjoy having a console for dev-testing when I run the app from debugger or manually on the command-line, so I wonder if /CONSOLE would make any differences to my program except the entrypoint (main VS WinMain) when deployed for real i.e. in terms of COM which we use quite a bit?

Does it really matter what entry-point signature I use? If I build /CONSOLE for ease of testing will it have any side-effects?

[image]

Comment: No, it doesn't matter. The only difference is whether the process starts up attached to a console.

Answer (score 0):

`/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE` is for console based applications

`/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS` is for applications without a console.

For more details I suggest you could refer to the Doc:[/SUBSYSTEM (Specify Subsystem)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/subsystem-specify-subsystem?view=vs-2019)

The default entry point for `/subsystem:console` is `mainCRTStartup`, for `/subsystem:windows` it's `WinMainCRTStartup`. It just so happens that the CRT implements those two functions and these implementations call main and WinMain, respectively. Thus, main and WinMain become the entry point for the programmer with which the linker as almost nothing to do.

I suggest you could refer to the Doc:[/ENTRY (Entry-Point Symbol)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/entry-entry-point-symbol?view=vs-2017)